# Tag for Ratchet and Clank Going Commando

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242103/106901) I saw that it was incorrectly tagged. So I changed it to [ratchet-and-clank-going-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-going-commando) but this is too long. So instead I changed it to [ratchet-and-clank-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-2).

While it's true that it's the 2nd one in the series, the proper name is Ratchet and Clank: Going Commando. So what should the tag be for it?

According to some previous tags for ratchet and clank, the tag could be [rnc-going-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-going-commando). This however will need a synonym starting with ratchet so it appears as a suggested tag.

Comment: Ratchet and Clank 2 -> rnc going commando? I would also propose another synonym given your argument. It was not called going commando, here in Australia. Had I not done wiki work on the game when I was young, the tag name would confuse me.

Comment: Yeah. Here it was "locked and loaded"

Comment: See also: [Have “Ratchet and Clank” specific tags appear when you type “Ratchet”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/have-ratchet-and-clank-specific-tags-appear-when-you-type-ratchet), which explains the 'rnc' naming convention

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

At some point after the tag limit [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), this tag was renamed [ratchet-and-clank-2-going-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-2-going-commando).

Strangely, [the linked question history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/242103/revisions) seems to claim the tag was renamed by Aequitas before this meta post was made.

I wasn't able to find any record of this rename in the [tag synonyms list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), meaning the old tags were likely deleted, rather than synonimized.

Comment: I renamed it as part of the 35 char update. The ratchet tags were some of the "test" tags we used to check if 35 char tags broke anything, and is listed on [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12500/28182) as having been changed at that time.